# Adding `git config` Command to Local `.git...` File

Tags: git

If I fail to set the following `git config` settings (see below), my build breaks.

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Can I add this particular command to a version-controlled `.git...` file to ensure that `https://` is always used instead of `git` to prevent this error for folks to clone this project but forget to set this config?

Comment: how do you check it out?

Comment: `git clone /path/to/project/url.git`

Comment: Wouldn't the better option be fixing your build so it doesn't break?